# Sql: Avoiding external merge from group by in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a fairly simple query which gets the top ten scores of a large table (just under 10 million rows) and returns them in descending order.  The scores are made up of sums aggregated using a group by clause, and the group by seems especially costly, using `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 190080k`

Is there some way I can speed this up?  I already have indices on user.test_id and user.score (descending).  I'd prefer not to change `work_mem` as I have limited control over our postgres settings.

Query:

```
select 
    (select test from test where top_scores.test_id = test.id), 
    (select type from test where top_scores.test_id = test.id), 
    sum_score
    from (select sum(score) as sum_score, 
          test_id
          from user
          group by test_id
          order by sum_score desc
          limit 10
    ) top_scores
```

Query Plan:

```
Subquery Scan on top_scores  (cost=1412662.62..1412831.69 rows=10 width=16) (actual time=164098.107..164098.714 rows=10 loops=1)"
  ->  Limit  (cost=1412662.62..1412662.64 rows=10 width=16) (actual time=164098.042..164098.144 rows=10 loops=1)"
        ->  Sort  (cost=1412662.62..1419366.96 rows=2681736 width=16) (actual time=164098.033..164098.067 rows=10 loops=1)"
              Sort Key: (sum(user.score)) DESC"
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB"
              ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1271799.65..1354711.27 rows=2681736 width=16) (actual time=72815.313..152605.093 rows=2499234 loops=1)"
                    Group Key: user.test_id"
                    ->  Sort  (cost=1271799.65..1290497.74 rows=7479234 width=16) (actual time=72815.273..107823.507 rows=7479234 loops=1)"
                          Sort Key: user.test_id"
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 190080kB"
                          ->  Seq Scan on user  (cost=0.00..162238.34 rows=7479234 width=16) (actual time=0.009..33795.669 rows=7479234 loops=1)"
  SubPlan 1"
    ->  Index Scan using test_id_idx on test  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.012..0.016 rows=1 loops=10)"
          Index Cond: (top_scores.test_id = id)"
  SubPlan 2"
    ->  Index Scan using test_id_idx on test test_1  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=3) (actual time=0.006..0.010 rows=1 loops=10)"
          Index Cond: (top_scores.test_id = id)"
Planning time: 0.724 ms"
Execution time: 164135.458 ms"
```

After suggestions by @jjanes in his answer, tried creating the following indices:

```
create index user_score_test_id_idx on user (score, test_id); 
create index user_test_id_score_idx on user (test_id, score);` 
create index user_test_id_score_desc_idx on user (test_id, score desc nulls last);
create index user_score_desc_test_id_idx on user (score desc nulls last, test_id);
```

and running `full vacuum user`

This had no discernible effect on execution time, and the resulting query plan was the exact same as without them. (put it in a diff checker and the only thing different was the times)

Edit: Apparently `full vacuum` wasn't what I wanted.  Just needed `vacuum`

Comment: 9.5 is EOL. This isn't just nagging, newer versions have features that may help you.

Comment: Good to know.  Unfortunately I don't control it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect separate indexes on test_id and score to help here.  But a multicolumn index on `(test_id, score)` should get use of an index-only scan and so avoid the sort.  If it doesn't immediately help, then VACUUM the table to get the visibility map bits set.

Also, your hardware appears to be spectacularly bad, or maybe just extremely overloaded.

Comment: Tried this, but no luck.  Query plan is identical.  Updated the question to show exactly what I tried.

Comment: Also, this is just postgres running in docker on my macbook pro :P

Comment: Is there a cost : actual time ratio that tipped you off?  How did you know the performance was bad?  What would be acceptable performance?

Comment: @b15 If you did `vacuum full`, that would be counter productive as it deletes the visibility map.  You would need to follow on with a regular `vacuum` to get it set again

Comment: That brought it down to about 1/3 of the time.  Thanks boss.  Had no idea `vacuum` was such a critical part of testing new indices.  I had tried the composite index earlier and thought it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select
    test, type, sum_score
from 
    test 
join
    (select 
        sum(score) as sum_score, 
        test_id
     from 
        user
     group by 
        test_id
     order by 
        sum_score desc
     limit 
        10
      ) top_scores
on 
   test.test_id = top_scores.test_id
```

Comment: Why join in the expensive part of the query when I only need that information for the top 10?  As far as I can tell from the query plan the inner queries im doing for test and type of the top ten are negligible.

Can you explain your reasoning?